# 'Inverse' property of a group and the special case that makes a group an Abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

One of the property for which a set must have in order to be a group is to possesses the 'inverse' property.

What this says is that for *each* element $a$ in $G$, there is an element $b$ in $G$ with $ab = ba = e$ where $e$ is the identity element.

In the special case where, in addition to the above 'inverse' property, if $ab = ba$ for all $a,b \in G$, we defined $G$ to be an Abelian group.

My confusion lies in the difference between the logical interpretation of the 2 properties: 
Am I correct to interpret " for each element $a$ in $G$" as being equivalent to "for all element $a$ in $G$"?
In other words, 
Let $G$ be the set $G=\{a_1,a_2,...,b,...,a_n\}$ and $b$ is unique
Then, by the inverse property, we have $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}.b=e$.

secondly, what is the difference between " there is an element $b$ in $G$" and "for all element $b$ in $G$"?

Comment: Your first interpretation is incorrect. Moreover, you can actually show that the inverse of each element is unique.

Answer (score 1):

One has to be careful about the ORDER (sequence) of logical quantifiers. The usual way the existence of inverses in a group is quantified is like so:

$\forall a \in G,\ \exists b \in G: a\ast b = b\ast a = e_G$.

This means we get a $b$ that may very well (and it turns out indeed does) depend on $a$.

Your "interpretation" is the following:

$\exists b \in G: \forall a \in G, a\ast b = b\ast a = e_G$

Notice how "swapping" the order of the quantifiers now says something *completely different*. Now it says that a SINGLE $b$ will work for ANY (and every) $a$.

Of course, the "second version" is the language (or logical version thereof) used to describe the identity:

$\exists e \in G: \forall a \in G, a\ast e = e\ast a = a$.

So your confusion is understandable, both the identity axiom and the inverse axiom of group theory are both labelled: "existence of...", and the niceties of the distinction of the two KINDS of existence are often glossed over.

Put another way: the identity element is a *distinguished* element of $G$, that acts on all other elements of $G$ in the same way: leaving them unchanged via multiplication. Inverses, on the other hand, only "undo" (or invert) what they are inverses OF, their scope is *limited*.

It is possible, in some algebraic structures you need not worry about just yet, for identities and/or inverses to be "only one-sided", and this can make it possible for them to be non-unique. However, in groups, this cannot happen: any group identity, is *necessarily* unique, for if we had another, say $e'$, then:

$e = e\ast e' = e'$.

In a similar vein, if an element $a$ had two, two-sided inverses, say $b,b'$, then:

$b = e\ast b = (b' \ast a)\ast b = b'\ast (a \ast b) = b' \ast e = b'$

We can say even more: suppose $a \ast b = a' \ast b = e$ (that is, $b$ is a right-inverse to $a$ and $a'$). If we are in a group, we know that $b$ has an inverse $b'$, so:

$(a \ast b) \ast b' = (a' \ast b)\ast b'$

$a\ast(b\ast b') = a'\ast(b\ast b')$

$a\ast e = a'\ast e$

$a = a'$, so $b$ can only be an inverse to a SINGLE group element.

In short, we have shown that for ANY group $G$, the mapping:

$g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is a BIJECTION (one-to-one and onto).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the important thing is to realize that different element may have different inverse. For example, $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group. Consider $3$ and $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. It is correct to say that these two elements have inverse. But keep in mind that their inverses are different! Indeed, $3$ has inverse $(-3)$, and $5$ has inverse$(-5)$.

To answer your second question, no, they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse property says that for each $a\in G$ you can find at least one element $b \in G$ such that $ab=ba=e$. You can now use the associativity to show that it must be unique, since if $ac=ca=e$ also, then $c=ce=c(ab)=(ca)b=eb=b$. But if I choose a different $a'\in G$ , then I will get a different inverse element $b'\in G$ such that $a'b'=b'a'=e$, and it is not true that $a'b=e$ (and in particular that $\{a_1 ,...,a_n\}\cdot b \neq \{e\}$.

Think for example inside the group of integers. For every $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ there is exactly one integer $m$ such that $m+n=n+m=0$, namely $m=-n$. When I go to $n+1$ its inverse is $-(n+1) \neq -n$.

When you say something like "for each element $a\in G$" some "statement" $P(a)$ happens, it means that if I choose some $a\in G$ no matter which one, the statement $P(a)$ is true. For example "P(a)= there is at least one element $b$ such that $ab=e$". Notice that the $b$ is chosen according to $a$. Another example - "For each rational number $q$, we can find another rational $r$ such that $2r=q$.